# FileAndDirectory Object in python

Tags: python, parsing, object

I am parsing a flat binary file that contains files and (their) directories concatenated together in a special format (with headers, indexes, etc). While parsing I want to create a python FileAndDirectory Object for each of them. My code for the FileAndDirectory Object is as follows:

```
class FileAndDirectory(object):
    def __init__(self, name, path, children):
        self.name = name
        self.path = path
        self.children = []
        #children = children.append(LIFFile)
        self.isDirectory = True
        self.fileOffset = -1
        self.fileSize = -1

    def __init__(self, name, path, fileOffset, fileSize):
        children = []
        self.name = name
        self.isDirectory = False
        #self.children = children.append(LIFFile)
        self.fileOffset = fileOffset
        self.fileSize = fileSize
        self.path = path

    def toString():
        return self.name
```

So in case of parsing a file I create it as follows (and this works):

```
parsedFile = FileAndDirectory(name, fullPath, offsetInLIF, fileSize)
```

In case of parsing a directory I intend to call (but this doesn't):

```
folderContentsList.append(childFile)

 return FileAndDirectory(folderName, pathThusFar, folderContentsList)
```

And I get the following error:

```
return FileAndDirectory(folderName, pathThusFar, folderContentsList)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)
```

And idea on how I can invoke the object with 2 different signatures in python ? A code similar to this would work in Java imho.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating multiple `__init__` methods, which doesn't work in Python because the second one 'overwrites' the first, you have two options:

1. Use keyword arguments:

   ```
   class FileAndDirectory(object):
       def __init__(self, name, path, children=None,
                    file_offset=None, file_size=None)
           ...
   ```

   The problem with this is that you need to remember which set of inputs are required for different types of things you are creating.
2. So the second option is to have multiple separate constructors, which are usually achieved in Python using classmethods or staticmethods. These typically wrap the normal constructor. It looks like this:

   ```
   class FileAndDirectory(object):
       @classmethod
       def create_file(cls, name, full_path, file_offset, file_size):
           return cls(name, full_path, file_offset=file_offset,
                      file_size=file_size)

       @classmethod
       def create_directory(cls, name, full_path, children):
           return cls(name, full_path, children=children)
   ```

   You would then use these like:

   ```
   FileAndDirectory.create_file(name, full_path, offset_in_LIF, file_size)
   FileAndDirectory.create_directory(folder_name, path_thus_far,
                                 folder_contents_list)
   ```

   As explanation - when you call a normal instance method the `self` parameter becomes the instance that is being called 'from'. When you call a classmethod, the `cls` parameter is the class that is called from (which could in fact be a subclass if there are any). The `cls(...)` call then does the same as `FileAndDirectory(...)` i.e. it calls the constructor and initializer. This code might be surprising to someone from a Java background - it Python, classes are runtime objects that can be passed around and used just the same as instances of classes.

A final consideration - if you need two different constructors, that suggests to me that two different classes for these objects might be preferable. If they have some similarities, they could inherit from a base class that has the shared behaviour.  But you know this better than me!

(Note - I 'corrected' all your code to use PEP8 variable name conventions, it's the standard in Python and you may as well get used to it).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ! I agree with the final consideration. I would love to use 2 different classes. Unfortunately I am dealing with legacy code and currently can't split it.

Comment: If this answer is acceptable, you should upvote/accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I must say I sympathize your Java mindset (as I'm also a beginner in Python) but I keep getting amazed by Python's pros and therefore tries to embrace them!

Fortunately in Python we can use a tuple of various object types. Use it as the constructor's parameter and then check its length inside the constructor:

```
def __init__(self, inputs):
    if len(inputs) == 3:
        # Parse a directory
    elif len(inputs) == 4:
        # Parse a file
```